# aws-sdk-go-v2 PutObject api error AccessDenied

Tags: go, amazon-s3, access-denied, aws-sdk-go, aws-sdk-go-v2

In our Staging environment, we have credential-less access to our private S3 buckets.  Access is granted to individual Docker containers.  I am trying to upload a file using `PutObject` using the aws-sdk-go-v2 SDK library, but I'm continually getting a 403 AccessDenied api error.

My upload code looks like this:

```
var uploadFileFunc = func(s3Details S3Details, key string, payload []byte, params MetadataParams) (*s3.PutObjectOutput, error) {
    client := getS3Client(s3Details)

    return client.PutObject(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:      aws.String(s3Details.Bucket),
        Key:         aws.String(key),
        Body:        bytes.NewReader(payload),
        ContentType: aws.String("text/xml"),
    })
}

func getS3Client(s3Details S3Details) *s3.Client {
    endpointResolver := aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(func(service, region string, options ...interface{}) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
        if s3Details.EndpointUrl != "" {
            return aws.Endpoint{
                PartitionID:   "aws",
                URL:           s3Details.EndpointUrl,
                SigningRegion: s3Details.Region,
                SigningMethod: s3Details.SignatureVersion,
            }, nil
        }
        return aws.Endpoint{}, &aws.EndpointNotFoundError{}
    })

    cfg, _ := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        config.WithEndpointDiscovery(aws.EndpointDiscoveryEnabled),
        config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(endpointResolver))

    return s3.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(o *s3.Options) {
        o.Region = s3Details.Region
        o.Credentials = aws.AnonymousCredentials{}
        o.UsePathStyle = true
    })
}
```

I am using `aws.AnonymousCredentials{}` (as our access is credential-less) but this is only to be used for unsigned requests.  I cannot use `NewStaticCredentialsProvider` with empty values for `AccessKeyID` and/or `SecretAccessKey` as this will throw a `StaticCredentialsEmptyError` during the `Retrieve()`.  Adding dummy credentials will throw an error that they are not on record.  I am assuming that this is the cause of my `403 AccessDenied`.

How do I sign requests without providing credentials in the Go SDK?  Is it even possible?  In the boto3 Python library this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'll strongly suggest you use the v2 of the AWS SDK of Go. I'll present here how I do this so far.
First, I get the AWS config to use with this code (only relevant parts are shown):

```golang
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        Log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Here the package used is `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config`.
Then, I instantiate an s3Client to use for contacting AWS S3 service:

```golang
s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(*cfg)
```

Here, we use this package `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3`. Finally, to post your object you have to run this code:

```golang
input := &s3.PutObjectInput{
    Key:    aws.String("test"),
    Bucket: aws.String("test"),
    Body:   bytes.NewReader([]byte("test")),
    ACL:    types.ObjectCannedACLPrivate,
}

if _, err := s3Client.PutObject(context.TODO(), input); err != nil {
    return "", fmt.Errorf("fn UploadFile %w", err)
}
```

The new package used here is `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types`.
This code is a simplification but you should able to achieve what you need. Furthermore, it should take very little time to update the version of the SDK and you can rely on both of them simultaneously if you've to work with a huge codebase.
Let me know if this helps!

### Edit

I updated my solution by using the `aws.AnonymousCredentials{}` option. Now I was successfully able to upload a file into an s3 bucket with these options. Below you can find the entire solution:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types"
)

func GetAwsConfig() (*aws.Config, error) {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        // config.WithClientLogMode(aws.LogRequestWithBody|aws.LogResponseWithBody),
        config.WithRegion("eu-west-1"),
        config.WithHTTPClient(&http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
        }}),
        config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(
            aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(func(service, region string, options ...interface{}) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
                return aws.Endpoint{
                    PartitionID:       "aws",
                    URL:               "http://127.0.0.1:4566",
                    SigningRegion:     "eu-west-1",
                    HostnameImmutable: true,
                }, nil
            }),
        ))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &cfg, err
}

func main() {
    cfg, _ := GetAwsConfig()
    s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(*cfg, func(o *s3.Options) {
        o.Credentials = aws.AnonymousCredentials{}
    })

    if _, err := s3Client.PutObject(context.Background(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("mybucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("myfile"),
        Body:   bytes.NewReader([]byte("hello")),
        ACL:    types.ObjectCannedACLPrivate,
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Before running the code, you've to create the bucket. I used the below command:
`aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://mybucket`
Thanks to this you can upload the file into the `mybucket` s3 bucket. To check for the file existence you can issue this command:
`aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --human-readable`
Hope this helps in solving your issue!

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your answer.  So does the `types.ObjectCannedACLPrivate` sign the request with v4?  I've updated to use v2 of the SDK as you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. The `types.ObjectCannedACLPrivate` deals only with grants & permissions assigned for that object. It's not related to signature v4.

Comment: Answer just updated, let me know!

Comment: @MeanwhileInHell any news about the question?